# from random matrix to symmetric matrix? (change of basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Is it possible to go from a random matrix (corresponding to a lineair tranformation) to a symmetric matrix by a change of basis? I think that it's possible iff the matrix is diagonalizable and that the eigenvectors form a perpendicular basis. Are there matrices who are diagonalizable and whose eigenvectors form a perpendicular basis that are not symmetric?

Comment: Just slap an inner product not conformal to the original and still express the linear transformation with respect to the original basis, the resulting matrix is still a symmetric matrix but the eigenbasis are now not orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

Any diagonalizable linear transformation is represented by a symmetric matrix in some basis (for instance, in a basis where it's represented by a diagonal matrix).

If a linear transformation is represented by a symmetric matrix in some basis, then diagonalizing that symmetric matrix gives you a basis where this linear transformation is represented by a diagonal matrix.

So given a linear transformation, the following two are equivalent:

- The linear transformation is diagonalizable
- There is a basis where the linear transformation is represented by a symmetric matrix

Comment: so there does not neccasairaly exist a basis of eigenvectors which is perpendicular? Considering me that's not in line with the Spectral theorem which says that a lineair transformation which corresponds to symmetric matrix has a perpendicular  basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: @marie That theorem requires that your basis (or bases) is orthonormal. And if you're only working with orthonormal bases, then no basis change can make a non-symmetric matrix into a symmetric matrix, or vice versa.

Comment: @marie It doesn't make sense to say "perpendicular" unless you have an inner product, which is not a given in this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot so if for example the standard inner product is given, then your transformation should have also an orthonormal basis?

Comment: @marie Transformations don't have bases. Spaces have bases. And linear transformations, if we have chosen a basis, have matrix representations. If we also have an inner product, then the linear transformations which have an orthonormal set of basis vectors which span the space are exactly the ones which are represented by symmetric matrices in any orthonormal basis.